Error:; Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu - not found
I installed ubuntu 24.04 on older Dell laptop (originally window 8) intel 3i processor.
After the error (Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu - not found) it loads grub and then boots to ubuntu. Everything is fine until I go into the files of the OS. The computer locks up. Reference boot-info https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rMMm7spNCf/. I ran boot repair with no change. I think the original UEFI is preventing a proper boot.

You are showing only one ESP - efi system partition, sda1 and UEFI entry uses correct partUUID to find ESP and ESP has correct UUID of sda2 to find Ubuntu/grub. Not seeing issue. And if before grub, its often UEFI trying to boot older install, but you have default set to boot Ubuntu and do not show an older install.  Even if older system, does Dell have UEFI firmware update?

To reiterate the question:
You are running Ubuntu in a dual boot system on aging hardware in UEFI boot mode. You (suddenly) started seeing the following message at boot time (after POST):

Failed to open  \EFI\ubuntu\ - Not Found

This problem started arising recently for the first generation of UEFI systems, that do support UEFI-boot but don't support secure boot.
In order to validate this, you can check if your system supports secure boot with command:
$ mokutil --sb-state

To fix the problem you can instruct grub to not use secure boot:
$ sudo grub-install --no-uefi-secure-boot /dev/nvme0n1
$ sudo update-grub

Note that you should replace /dev/nvme0n1 with the drive that grub is installed on and loaded from. You can find out by inspecting the output of command:
$ lsblk -e 7

At your next boot the failure message after POST should be gone.

I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my fairly old ASUSTek K53U laptop but it can boot from EFI by pressing ESC on startup or from BIOS by pressing F2.
I installed from BIOS and got the error message "Failed to open /EFI/Ubuntu...".
I installed from EFI and the error no longer appeared.
You may need to press another key to boot from the EFI window.
I have other PC, old too Acer Aspire One, and to boot from EFI, you need to press F12.
it is a BIOS issue.
You can find this information in the right side of the BIOS window or in the user manual.
The name and model are in the Bios window.

I also have this error after installing Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS from a USB stick. When I booted the USB stick normally, it only offered to install an MBR (ca. 1 MB). I only found the option to boot it in UEFI mode by typing F10 during BIOS startup.  That revealed two UEFI boot options for the USB stick (created on a Windows PC using Rufus) but only the first option would execute. To sum up, I have installed Ubuntu (single-boot) from UEFI but I also get the error described. The needed directory and files under /boot/efi/ do exist, according to "sudo efibootmgr -v"
